# Use splint to detect always false if logic flow

Tags: c, static-code-analysis, splint

Can a flag can be set with splint to detect this logic fault?

```
if((a > 0) && (a == 0)){...}
```

The 2nd variable `a` is a typo. It's supposed to be `b`.

I've tried `+ifempty` and `+ifblock` and it turns out that they are for something else. Any suggestions? Or is it beyond splint?

Comment: After taking a look at the [relevant documentation section](https://splint.org/manual/html/sec8.html) I think it's sadly beyond the tool's ability.

Comment: splint is long dead and obsolete. You might have better luck with more modern tools like clang/llvm's static analyzer.

Answer (score 1):

PVS-Studio can find such an error using the [V560](https://www.viva64.com/en/w/v560/) diagnostic. Example: https://godbolt.org/z/JA-Kmm